# queing jobs in threadpool vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, threadpool

i have 20,000 items in a queue, and i want to process them using the threadpool.
will this be the best way to do it?

```
for i as integer = 0 to 19999
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (PerformTask, ListTask(i))
next

Sub PerformTask(i as string)
' do the work here
end sub
```

How can i return or set ui control from the PerformTask sub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.

However, you can allocate a container (array, list) with a different slot for each result, and write into it. Alternatively, you could pass an object *into* the worker method that holds both the input and the result. I’d use this method:

```
Class TaskObject
    Dim Input As String
    Dim Result As Whatever
End Class

Dim tasks As TaskObject() = New TaskObject(20000) { }

For i as Integer = 0 to tasks.Length - 1
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(PerformTask, tasks(i))
next

Sub PerformTask(arg As Object)
    Dim task As TaskObject = DirectCast(arg, TaskObject)
    ' do the work here
end sub
```

Unrelated: you should *always* enable `Option Strict` in your projects. No exception. Your code has type errors that the compiler should detect.

Comment: thanks, how do i report progress to UI thread, can you include it in your code?